# Angularjs $emit from controller to $on in directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In angular 1.5, i have a controller with a function:

```
mobilesubmenu(element) {
    var vm = this;

    if (angular.isDefined(element.istitle)) {
        vm.$rootScope.$emit('hidemenu');
```

and in a directive:

```
restrict: 'C',
link: function($scope, $element) {
    $scope.$on('hidemenu', function (event) {
        $element.parent().parent().addClass('-hidden');
```

This works. But it bubbles up and has an effect on the parents elements up the dom tree (nested menu items: `ul > li > ul > li > ul > li`). And it also gets fired as many times as the directive is present in the page.

I've seen that to prevent this, i should be using `event.stopPropagation();` which `$emit` has when `$broadcast` does not.

Problem is, when switching method in the controller to `$emit`, the event is not being captured anymore by the directive.

A quick test in the same controller as some other level with

```
$rootScope.$on('hidemenu', function (event) {
    console.log('$on in controller');
}
```

reveals that the controllers receives well the event emitted with `$emit` though.

I have been searching for a while now and could not get a workaround yet.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You may clear the `$scope` event listener or try using the `$broadcast` method depending on your new dom tree implementation.

Comment: What task are you trying to solve? If you need to communicate between two directives, scope events aren't the best choice, because this is global event bus. Also ` $element.parent().parent()...` has distinct smell and suggests that directive design went wrong.

Comment: @estus the view holds an `ng-click` which goes to the controller that triggers an event for the directive to manipulate the dom.

Comment: @JosuéZatarain yes `broadcast` works but not in a good way. What do you mean by "clear the $scope event listener"?

Comment: @kevin Make the listener to stop listening, but given that you don't want it to replicate, I highly recommend to go for another solution.

Comment: Hope this helps http://www.codelord.net/2015/05/04/angularjs-notifying-about-changes-from-services-to-controllers/